# What to do when facts change frequently in a star schema for data warehouse?

Tags: data-warehouse, change-data-capture, dimensional-modeling, facttable, star-schema

I have a Quotation Management system that I built as a CRUD web app.

Over time, I realized I need to improve it so that management can have their reports.

Hence I studied the Kimball method of data warehousing.

I am now familiar with the concept of Dimensional and Fact tables.

On paper and pen, I have identified Quotation Line Item as the Fact table.

My issue is sometimes, the Sales Rep and the Customer have frequent back and forth regarding the Line Items so the line items will change quantities frequently or even removed.

I know that fact tables not supposed to have zero rows according to the Kimball book.

My question is how then do I handle such changes in the fact table?

According to a [source](http://blog.oaktonsoftware.com/2011/08/slowly-changing-facts.html), I am supposed to continuously update the fact table.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I don't need to track history then just add/update/delete the fact records as the Quotation Lines change.

If I do need to track history then add effective start and end dates to the fact table.

See [Timespan Accumulating Snapshot Fact Tables](http://www.kimballgroup.com/2012/05/design-tip-145-time-stamping-accumulating-snapshot-fact-tables/)

Credit goes to Nick White in this [thread](http://forum.kimballgroup.com/t3177-what-to-do-when-facts-change-update-the-fact-table-with-update-and-deletes-or-use-scd-type-2).